# GCP authorized session get method using python 3

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, parameters, get, request

Attempting to use GCP Authorized Session get method in Python to query data in GCP.  The doc shows:

get(url, **kwargs)
Sends a GET request. Returns Response object.

Parameters: 
url – URL for the new Request object.
**kwargs – Optional arguments that request takes.
Return type:
requests.Response

I set up a kwarg dict as kwargs = {'page_size': 2000'}

However, when I passed it to the call authsess.get('someurl', kwargs), I get the following error...

TypeError: get() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given.

It works fine using just the url, but, I will need to add parms (specifically a nextPageToken as if one is returned)

Can someone please give me a little guidance on what I am missing here?  Do I need to encode the url and parms together? or?  I have tried various options here, but, just can't get it to work and not sure yet just 'how' to interpret/implement what I find in the doc for making http requests...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

OK, sorry if I wasted anyone's time.  The answer is that I needed to add 'params=' to the beginning of the parameters string...  i.e., authsess.get('someurl', params=kwargs)

Really wish that had been mentioned in the doc....